# How to display 2 images at same time in winform

Tags: c#, winforms

In winforms I have two picture box one for portrait and other for Landscape. 
Do to the size of the file or some reasons they are not downloading at same time,

let say if portrait image downloaded  first,Now I click the updated button it was showing portrait image,
after second image downloaded when I click the update button it was showing Landscape image only.

I need both images should show, after downloading both images, but in my case it showing only one image(the latest downloaded image).

what should I do, Here is the code.

```
 private void DisplayLogos(LogoHeader imageHeader)
    {
        if (imageHeader.carId == 2)
        {
            PortraitLabel.Text = "Portrait Image";
            PortraitLabel.Visible = true;
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageHeader.Images.First());
            Image image = Image.FromStream(ms);
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(image);
            PortraitPictureBox.Image = image;
            PortraitPictureBox.Visible = true;
        }
        else if (imageHeader.carId == 1)
        {
            LandscapeLabel.Text = "Landscape Image  ";
            LandscapeLabel.Visible = true;
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageHeader.Images.First());
            LandscapePictureBox.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
            LandscapePictureBox.Visible = true;
        }                   
    }

public class LogoHeader 
{
    public LogoHeader(Access au, int Id)
    {
        carId = Id;
    }
    public int carId { get; set; }
    public byte[] image{ get; set; }

    public List<byte[]> Images
    {
        get
        {
            List<byte[]> logos = new List<byte[]>();
            logos.Add(image);            
            return logos;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Do i follow any design patterns, In order to work

Answer (score 0):

In order to keep the image you can't close (or change) the stream, you can simply create another one.

```
private void DisplayLogos(LogoHeader imageHeader)
{
    if (imageHeader.carId == 2)
    {
        PortraitLabel.Text = "Portrait Image";
        PortraitLabel.Visible = true;
        MemoryStream ms1 = new MemoryStream(imageHeader.Images.First());
        Image image = Image.FromStream(ms1);
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(image);
        PortraitPictureBox.Image = image;
        PortraitPictureBox.Visible = true;
    }
    else if (imageHeader.carId == 1)
    {
        LandscapeLabel.Text = "Landscape Image  ";
        LandscapeLabel.Visible = true;
        MemoryStream ms2 = new MemoryStream(imageHeader.Images.First());
        LandscapePictureBox.Image = Image.FromStream(ms2);
        LandscapePictureBox.Visible = true;
    }                   
}
```

Comment: Thanks, here I add a condition that if CarId ==2 then it is portrait image, If landscape image downloaded it skipping portrait, and vise-versa